# my spring Boot project has a h2 database, now I would like to change the hd database to mysql database, how should I go about?

Tags: mysql, spring

my spring Boot project has a h2 database, now I would like to change the h2 database to mysql database, how should I go about it? I have added mysql dependency to my pom.xlm. and have changed my application.properties files accordingly. Do I have to create the a table manually mysql database? I know with h2 database you just define your table in data.sql in "resources" folder. what else do I have to do differently to be able to connect to mysql databse?

Comment: What happened after you made those changes and the application was run?

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

`data.sql` is a spring convention, not h2's. As long as the sql query that's inside works with `mysql` then it'll run all the same. All you have to do is change `spring.datasource.url` in `application.properties`.

Usually we switch this using profiles. A `local` profile to use h2 and a `dev` profile to use mysql. You can name them however you prefer of course.

Comment: I have added a table manually in the mysql database, when run the app I do not get any errors and nothing is written to table either. in console  I see this:  main] ication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d02b9558 :  course 1001 --->null  (instead of of null I should see data.). this is my: logger.info(" course 10001 --->{}", course); from main class.  here is also my aplication.properties: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=12345

Comment: The question is that are there any errors during startup? Spring shouldn't start if they couldn't connect to the database. One easy way to test this is to change the port of `spring.datasource.url` to something wrong. If spring fails to start means that your current connection is correct. if it's correct then make sure you're connected to the correct schema and the tables exists

Comment: no, there is no  error at the startup. do I have to create  the same table in "data.sql" file  in my resources folder like I do for h2 databse? or I mysql table is enough?

Comment: basically yes. Imagine you have an empty h2 or mysql database. Write all the queries that you need from that point onwards until it's usable by your application

Comment: I connecte to mysql DB. I still have my  "data.sql" file in resources folder (it is a  in memory database), now, how can I insert in data mysql tables?   manually  or are there any other way? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/studentdbdbcreateDatabaseIfNotExist=TRUE&&serverTimezone=America/Chicago
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

for more information visit 
https://devkonline.com/tutorials/content/Spring-Boot-2-Hibernate-JPA-MYSQL-REST-API